# MySQL subquery returning more than one result

Tags: php, mysql, calendar, pdo

Does someone figures out a way to make this code works even when **MySQL subquery** returns more than one result? It is working fine when the user has no event related to him, or when the user has one event related to him, but when a **user is related to more than one event**, the subquery returns more than one result and than the code gets nothing to work with.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE
                  id_events = ( SELECT id_events FROM relationship_events WHERE id_user = ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $idUser);
$stmt->execute();

$rawTimeStamps = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$cleanDateArray = array();

foreach ($rawTimeStamps as $t) {
$rawDate = $t['start'];
$rawDate = getdate($rawDate);
$cleanDate = mktime(0,0,0,$rawDate['mon'],$rawDate['mday'],$rawDate['year']);
$cleanDateArray[] = $cleanDate;
}

for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):

$calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day">';
    $timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$month,$list_day,$year);
    if (!empty($cleanDateArray) && in_array($timestamp, $cleanDateArray)) {

    $date = getdate($timestamp);
    $time_start = mktime(0,0,0,$date['mon'],$date['mday'],$date['year']);
    $time_end = mktime(23,59,59,$date['mon'],$date['mday'],$date['year']);
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT title FROM events WHERE start BETWEEN ? AND ?');
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$time_start,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$time_end,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $events = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $calendar.= '<div class="day-number day-number-event"><a href="#">'.$list_day.'</a></div><p>'.$events["title"].'</p>';
    } else {
    $calendar.= '<div class="day-number day-number-noevent">'.$list_day.'</div><div id="calendar-events"></div>';
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query should be `SELECT * FROM events WHERE id_events IN ( SELECT id_events FROM relationship_events WHERE id_user = ?)`.

Comment: THIS IS IT! Just using this logic of query has solved my problem! Even that I envolve another subquery (wich is another situation I'm in, it works fine!) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible answers, depending on how you want it to work.

If you only want a single event, regardless if the user has 1 or more events, you can add `LIMIT 1` in your subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE id_events = (
    SELECT id_events FROM relationship_events WHERE id_user = ? LIMIT 1
)
```

On the other hand, if you want *all* events assigned to the user, you can use an `IN` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE id_events IN (
    SELECT id_events FROM relationship_events WHERE id_user = ?
)
```

Both of these should also work fine if the user is assigned to no events.